# Difference between a series and an expansion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, taylor-expansion

In mathematics is there a difference between a series and an expansion? E.g. is a Taylor or Laurent series different from (respectively) a Taylor or Laurent expansion?

**My Guess**

From what I know I would say that a series is a sequence added together e.g. the series associated with $\{a_n\}$ is:
$$\sum_n a_n$$
whilst an expansion is a series related to another function $f$ in someway.

Comment: A Taylor expansion stops at some point, with a remainder term (either a $o()$ or $O()$ for the Peano form, the Lagrange or Cauchy remainder looking more like the mean-value theorem, the integral form of the remainder, [etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)). A series has not -- it is an exact form with no remainder.

Comment: A [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) is relative to a *function*, thus it is a particular case of [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)).

Comment: for your reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html